# Comment count same for every post in homepage WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I have a WP_Query on my homepage template that works just fine for get_the_title() and MANY other functions for each post in the loop.

However, any way of getting the comment count just grabs the real count for the first post and then repeats the same output for the rest of the posts.

I've tried both `echo get_comments_number($post->ID);` and `comments_number();`

The kicker: if I use the same template NOT on the homepage, comment count works fine.

Comment: I would paste my code here but it's a very complex template for handling many post types. Can do a pastebin if required.

Comment: Try wp_reset_postdata() or wp_reset_query(). If it doesn't work, please paste the full code of homepage template in pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Switching out `echo get_comments_number($post->ID)` for `echo $post->comment_count` did the trick.

I have no idea why, that's exactly what the `get_comments_number()` function does...